# ReferenceError: require is not defined when importing ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

So I am getting this strange error, **ReferenceError: require is not defined** when importing ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'. Without importing ApolloClient app is running but when importing it shows error.
Screenshot of the error is in the image attached:
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSmIa.jpg)

## Here is my Code

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';

import  ApolloClient  from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';


const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri:"http://localhost:4444/graphql"
})
ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install graphql v14.0.2** (or new one).  Graphql package must be in your package.json.

For more see original solution here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/299#issuecomment-421784547

Answer (score 1):

Go to ***node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config*** (both dev && prod files)

```
{
  test: /\.mjs$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  type: "javascript/auto"
},
```

past the above code inside `rules: [`